# xpra attach failure

Tags: x11, xpra

After entering the command to attach to an xpra session:

```
xpra attach ssh:SERVERNAME:100
```

we get this response:

```
connection lost: empty marker in read queue
Connection lost
```

What does it mean? We can see the xpra session running on the server.

Comment: Your particular msg. showed up in this issue: http://xpra.org/trac/ticket/64. Not sure if it's related but you might want to take a look. I found very little else beyond this, so you're going to have to look through xpra's logs and possibly turn up the verbosity/debug levels to get more info to go on.

Comment: Are you connecting from Precise to a Trusty server by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your version is too old, but your question really lacks details.

What Operating System? Version? Have you tried connecting locally (not via SSH), or via TCP? What does your server log file say? What command did you use to start the server? etc..